# What's the appropriate "workflow" tool in IBM WebSphere?

Tags: websphere

I'm using IBM RAD 7.5 and WebSphere.

What would be the appropriate tool to implement a document approval workflow with those technologies?  I was looking at open source tools like jBPM and Activiti, but it seems like there should be something built in I could use.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_BPEL_engines
http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_moteurs_de_workflow

Comment: Thanks for the link, but is there already a similar technology built in WebSphere that I get out of the box?

Comment: IBM Business Process Manager is one of the tools that you could consider. It is a BPM tool not a workflow engine per se. You also have FileNet BPM product which would be good for document centric flows. Both these products use WAS as the base engine. You can check them out and see if they meet your needs

Answer (score 0):

IBM WCM (which comes with portal depending on your license) has a workflow engine built for content management purposes (review, approval, notifications, etc) and it can be extended with custom workflow actions. If you build a wcm wrapper (a piece of descriptive content to attach your document to, you could do pretty much anything you need)